# Is there a better way to implement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am asking the user 10 multiple choice questions once the questions are answered I would like a result to appear based on  their answers. I was wondering if there was a better method of figuring out their score then just doing lots of if statements?

```
Int result = 100;
if (answer1 == 10) {
  result = result +10;

  if (answer2 ==20 ) {
    result = result -5;

    if (answer3 == 50) {
      result = result +20;
    }
    else if (answer3 == 10)

    ...
```

and it will carry on...

Comment: What is the logic? when do you add how much to result?

Comment: Properly indent code with proper usage of braces

Comment: At the very least, you should format your code better.

Comment: just a thought... case statement may be? if you are doing repeative thing than using loop and case statement will give you result.

Comment: Also note, using `if`s is not realy a possibility, since you will have to write `k^10` of those for 10 multiple choice answers, where `k` is number of possibilities. Even if `k==2`, it leads to 1024 if statements - which you don't want to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Oh wait, I see it's nested.. You could still go for a look-up solution. Instead of `Map<String, Integer>`, you could use something like `Map<Map<String,Boolean>, Integer>` where the Integer is the final score.

---

This is one common way to do it:

```
Map<String, Integer> choice_delta = // new Map

// Define choice delta pairing
choice_delta.put("answer5", -5);
choice_delta.put("answer6", 20);
// etc. etc.

int calculate(String[] answers){
    int result = 0;
    for (String answer : answers){
        int delta = choice_delta.get(answer);
        result += delta;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is the way it should be done. This table driven method will give you more flexibility than the if statements; you can externalize the table initialization to make your application configurable for example. Another way to achieve this is to create classes like "Question" & "Answer".

Comment: Thank you, I modified the method you presented to me.

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to implement if you model it properly. I am not sure about your problem context but making few assumptions here is what I came up with.

**Narrative**

A `Quiz` is a set of `Question`'s. Each Question has one or more `Answer`'s, each Answer carrying a certain `weight`. You `prepare` the Quiz for a particular scenario (Java, c#) and present to the user one by one. User `selects` an answer for the presented question and then you display him the `currentScore` and next question. After all the questions are presented a `finalScore` is calculated.

**Abstractions**

- Quiz (prepare, currentScore(), finalScore())
- Question (scoreFor)
- Answer (weightedScore)

**Implementation**

```
public class Quiz
{
    List<Question>  questions       = new ArrayList<Question>();
    List<String>    selectedAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int     currentScore;

    public void prepare()
    {
        questions.add(new Question("What comes after A?", Arrays.asList(new Answer("B", 10), new Answer("Z", 5))));
        questions.add(new Question("What comes after B?", Arrays.asList(new Answer("A", -5), new Answer("C", 10))));
    }

    public int finalScore()
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++)
        {
            result = result + questions.get(i).scoreFor(selectedAnswers.get(i));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void setSelectedAnswerFor(int questionIndex, String selectedAnswer)
    {
        assert questionIndex < questions.size();
        selectedAnswers.add(questionIndex, selectedAnswer);
        currentScore = currentScore +    questions.get(questionIndex).scoreFor(selectedAnswer);
    }

    public int currentScore()
    {
        return currentScore;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
        quiz.prepare();
        quiz.setSelectedAnswerFor(0, "B");
        System.out.println("Current Score " + quiz.currentScore());
    quiz.setSelectedAnswerFor(1, "A");
    System.out.println("Current Score " + quiz.currentScore());
    System.out.println("Final Score " + quiz.finalScore());
    }
}

public class Question
{
    private final String                text;
    private final Map<String, Integer>  weightedAnswers;

    public Question(String text, List<Answer> possibleAnswers)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.weightedAnswers = new HashMap<String, Integer>(possibleAnswers.size());
        for (Answer ans : possibleAnswers)
        {
            weightedAnswers.put(ans.text, ans.score);
        }
    }

    public int scoreFor(String selectAnswer)
    {
        return weightedAnswers.get(selectAnswer);
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }
}

public class Answer
{
    final String    text;

    final int       score;

    public Answer(String text, int score)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.score = score;
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Current Score 10
Current Score 5
Final Score 5
```

## That solution can be enhanced but the point is to represent the solution in terms of business concepts ([ubiquitous language](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/132)) and the solution will come naturally. #

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if one goes beyond maybe 4-5 categories, I'll invent some sort of table-driven approach.  Precisely what would depend on the details (and my mood), but Enno's is a good one, and typical of the concept.